# I am trying to dynamically insert data in mysql using php and i am getting syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error, insert-query

Here is the query i am using:

```
$z = "INSERT INTO
       `ingridients`(`recipe_id`, `name`,`quantity`,`unit`)
       VALUES ('{$newid}','{${"igname".$j}}','{${"igq".$j}}','{${"igu".$j}}')";
```

I get a syntax error.

Comment: Which syntax error do you get?

Comment: You use doublequotes in double quotes. That is not allowed. you have to concatinate the strings, or better you use prepared statements.

Comment: curly braces everywhere.

Comment: i get this You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Comment: $z = "INSERT INTO `ingridients`(`recipe_id`, `name`,`quantity`,`unit`) VALUES (".$newid.",".${"igname".$j}.",".${"igq".$j}.",".${"igu".$j}.")";
    

This is what i am using now but still same error

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
$z = "INSERT INTO ingridients(recipe_id, name,quantity,unit) VALUES ('{$newid}','{${"igname".$j}}','{${"igq".$j}}','{${"igu".$j}}')";
```

into

```
$z = "INSERT INTO ingridients(recipe_id, name,quantity,unit) VALUES ( '$newid','$igname.$j','$igq.$j','$igu.$j' )";
```

**Update**

```
<?php

    for($j = 1; $j <= 25; $j++)
    {
        $igname.$j = $_POST['igname'.$j];
        $igq.$j = $_POST['igq'.$j];
        $igu.$j = $_POST['igu'.$j];
        if($igname.$j != "")
        {
            $z = "INSERT INTO ingridients(recipe_id, name,quantity,unit) VALUES ( '$newid','$igname.$j','$igq.$j','$igu.$j' )";
            $z = mysql_query($z);
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: this inserts some junk data in database instead of the data in that variable

Comment: @Niraj from where you are getting data? what is in `$igname`?

Comment: FORM and $igname is not a seperate variable

for($j=1;$j<=25;$j++)
    {
    ${"igname".$j} = $_POST['igname'.$j];
    ${"igq".$j} = $_POST['igq'.$j];
    ${"igu".$j} = $_POST['igu'.$j];
    if(${"igname".$j} != "")
    {
       $z = "INSERT INTO `ingridients`(recipe_id, name,quantity,unit) VALUES ($newid,${"igname".$j},${"igq".$j},${"igu".$j})";
        //$z = "INSERT INTO `ingridients`(`recipe_id`, `name`,`quantity`,`unit`) VALUES (".${"igname".$j}.",".${"igname".$j}.",".${"igq".$j}.",".${"igu".$j}.")";
 
        $z = mysql_query($z);

Answer (score 0):

try to do with following code

```
   $z = "INSERT INTO
   ingridients(recipe_id, name,quantity,unit)
   VALUES ('".$newid."','".$igname.$j."','".$igq.$j."','".$igu.$j."')";
```